# Как отправить POST запрос на HTTPS?

Tags: delphi, post, https

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как средствами Delphi7 отправить POST запрос на HTTPS (ругается на меня очень сильно).
Отправляла через инди IDhttp.
Если слать на HTTP, то не ругается. А если добавить букву S, то сразу же ругань.
И ещё, кто нибудь знает сниф на HTTPS?

Comment: [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) отличный прокси/снифер.

Comment: Чем ругается то? Что именно говорит? Попробуйте отключить проверку сертификатов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дельфях используйте набор компонентов, работающих с SSL, иначе - никак! HTTPS не обрабатывает запросы, поступившие от "некого левого приложения" или сайта, он их сбрасывает. Поэтому, только SSL, только хардкор =)